# Responsive layout on paper-drawer-panel not working

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I created a new `polymer` site and if i open it on my mobile phone the responsive design does not work. (But i should because it's a paper-drawer-panel)

==> https://www.sese7.de/polymer/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
</head>
<body>
    <home-main>
        <login-main>
        </login-main>
    </home-main>

</body>
</html>
```

Module:

```
<dom-module id="home-main">

<template>
    <style>
    </style>

    <paper-drawer-panel id="pdp">
        <div drawer style="background-color: #dfdfdf;">

        </div>
        <div main>
            <paper-toolbar>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            </paper-toolbar>

            <content></content>
        </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
</template>

<script>

    Polymer({
        is: "home-main"
    });

</script>

</dom-module>
```

Where is my problem? Sorry I'm new at polymer.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: However it is working if i scale down my browser **but** not when i open it on my mobile device or simulate it

Comment: This behavior can be adjusted with CSS so you should display the CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout does look responsive but it might look better on mobile devices if you added the proper meta tags to your HTML `<head>`. Try this :

```
<head>
    <!-- Add this -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
</head>
```